# Is there a way to disable the auto-indentation when pasting in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

I like the auto-indentation in XCode 4 when coding/typing, but I want to disable this function when I'm pasting the code. So is there a way to have separate settings for the two situations?

Answer (score 51):

Instead of using a normal paste, use "Paste and Preserve Formatting". It's in the Edit menu, and its shortcut is "Alt+Shift+Cmd+V".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! I never noticed the "Paste and Preserve Formatting" command. So, changing the "default" behaviour can be easily done by remapping the paste keyboard shortcut to this spacial paste action.

Comment: ... though "Paste and Preserve Formatting" unfortunately doesn't work everywhere "Paste" works, for example not in the search and replace input fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable or disable in Xcode 11
Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing > switch to `Re-indent on paste`

[image]

Answer (score -3):

No this option.

Why don't you use Re-Indent function via shortcuts after paste.

When you paste some code to current file, press Command+A to select all, then press ^I.

All the code will be re-indented.

Comment: This answer explains how to auto-indent pasted code. OP is looking for a way to **disable** the auto-indentation when pasting code.